# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I'm getting that error and below is the query that which is getting passed

```
insert into PROD_SUBTYPE_EXCEPTION_DETAILS
  (FILE_NAME,PRODUCT_CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION,PERIOD,P3,P15,TOTAL_AUM,TIME_STAMP,ID,REPORTING_YEAR)
values
 ('P_20130731.DAT','xxx',last_day(to_date('07'||'2013','MMYYYY')),'xxxx','xxx',8049792.04,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'eg12345',2010)
```

If I execute the same query in SQL Developer its working fine, but i'm getting that error if i pass it through my program.

and my java program is:

```
public int insert(String query, Object beanVO, Map<Integer, String> placeHolder)
    throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException,
           InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException {
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    Connection con = null;
    try {
        con = getConnection(true);
        pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
        setPstmtValues(pstmt, beanVO, placeHolder);
        int status=pstmt.executeUpdate();
        return status;  
    } 
    finally{
        if (isBatchMode)
        {
            this.cleanResources(null, pstmt);
        }
        else
        {
            this.cleanResources(con, pstmt);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the executing java code look like?

Comment: please share the stacktrace

Comment: do you have a semicolon at the end of your statement? I don't see it in what you have pasted, but if you can print the query before it gets executed, that would help. Typically SQL developer will not complain if there is one, but JDBC sees it as a threat.

Comment: Check with datatypes at program, check whether both match or not with columns type

Comment: I picked that query exactly from my log and posted it and there is no semicolon

Comment: Did you tried to wrap statement into procedure and then call procedure? You will gain increased speed performance and security. All you are able to do on database layer just do it there. This is always much more safe and of course faster.

Comment: When is that log message produced - is that the original `query`, or what JDBC logging shows, or is it coming from inside `setPstmtValues` - and what is that method doing? Do you have any quotes or control chars in your `xxx` values (I assume you've masked them)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry this code is working fine now, I called the wrong insert method so i got that exception.

Thank you all.